# When can you get current page ID and initialize hooks right after?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, actions, wp-enqueue-script

I'm developing a plugin and need to know on what page user is and then add specific hooks and filters for that page.
And my problem is that `is_page()` and `the_ID()` doesn't work outside of `wp`, `wp_loaded`, `init` actions, but if i use these actions then i can't initialize hooks because for them to work properly they must be added before those actions.
So my question being, is there any hook from witch i can call `the_ID()`, get a proper result **and then** add another hooks for that page? Or is it possible **only** using PHP's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The earliest safe hook to get post information is the `template_redirect` hook. All the hooks in question runs before Wordpress has setup postdata, so any post info are still unavailable at that point.

The globals like `$wp_query` and `$post` will still contain no data, that is why your efforts returns nothing.

### EDIT

Extra info as per comment by @TheDeadMedic

> Actually `wp` is an earlier, still-safe hook - just make sure to use `get_queried_object()` instead of relying on `$post` global

Comment: Actually `wp` is an earlier, still-safe hook - just make sure to use `get_queried_object()` instead of relying on `$post` global.

Comment: `template_redirect` is actually **exactly** what i needed, thank you! Also `wp` hook doesn't appear to work for me even with `get_queried_object()`, just returns `NULL`. But my problem is now solved thanks to you and this is what important.